# Avplayer item pre buffering while scrolling on UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I have created an UITableView with custom UITableViewCells. UITableView consists of images and videos that load via internet. While user is scrolling in one of the UITableViewCell i load AVPlayer to play a hls video. I set URL in hls format to the avplayer item in order to play the item.

```
self.playerController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
NSURL *videoURL = @"https://playeritemvideourl";
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
self.playerController.player = self.player;
[self.player play];
```

The video plays but there is a delay of about 3 to 5 seconds from the moment `[self.player play]` is triggered. How do i pre buffer the video to the currentitem of avplayer so when i scroll to the specific UITableViewCell the video starts playing instantly? I looked at `preferredForwardBufferDuration` property on AVPlayerItem but does not seem to make any difference. Any help or suggestions appreciated!

Comment: I have couple of questions 1) Your every cell has its own playerController? 2) are you trying to play mp4 ? or m3u8?

Comment: @SunilBhosale Hello sir thanks for responding. 1) Yes each cell has its own playercontroller 2) I am trying to play m3u8...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AVPlayer` begins streaming m3u8 when it is instantiated. (I noticed this by monitoring the Network graph in the Debug navigator in Xcode. I instantiated an AVPlayer without calling `-[play]` and the network was under load.) Instead of loading the `AVPlayer` once the cell becomes visible, *instantiate* the `AVPlayer` *before* the cell is visible and *play* the content *when it becomes* visible.

This can be implemented by first having some data structure hold the `AVPlayer` items. I would recommend a `NSMutableDictionary`, as we can set the key to the video's URL we want and the object can be the `AVPlayer` already loaded with the URL. There are two ways to populate the structure. You could load it all at once in a method like `-viewDidLoad` or load items in dynamically in `-scrollViewDidScroll:` to determine if we are close to a cell with a video. I would use the former if there is not a lot of content and the user is almost guaranteed to watch all the videos. I would use the latter if we have a lot of content to load or if the user might not watch all the videos. Here is an example with a `UITableViewController`.

**MyTableViewController.h**

```objectivec
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>

@interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSMutableDictionary *mediaPlayers; // stores the media players, key = NSString with URL, value = AVPlayer
    // you don't need mediaKeyIndexPaths or mediaKeyURLs if you are taking the load-all-at-once approach
    NSMutableSet *mediaKeyIndexPaths; // set that stores the key NSIndexPaths that trigger loading a media player
    NSDictionary *mediaKeyURLs; // dictionary that maps a key NSIndexPath to a URL (NSString), key = NSIndexPath, value = NSString
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayerViewController *playerController;

@end
```

**MyTableViewController.m**

```objectivec
#import "MyTableViewController.h"

@implementation MyTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // if you want to load all items at once, you can forget mediaKeyIndexPaths and mediaKeyURLs
    // and instead just load all of your media here
    mediaPlayers = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    
    // if taking the load-all-at-once approach, load mediaPlayers like this
//  NSString *videoURLString = @"https://playeritemvideourl";
//  AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURLString];
//  [mediaPlayers setObject:player forKey:@"https://playeritemvideourl"];

    // lets say that the cell with the media in it is defined here
    NSIndexPath *dummyMediaIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:40 inSection:0];
    // calculate an index path that, when visible, will trigger loading the media at dummyMediaIndexPath
    NSIndexPath *dummyKeyIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:dummyMediaIndexPath.row-10
                                                  inSection:dummyMediaIndexPath.section];
    
    // add the key index path to the set of key index paths
    mediaKeyIndexPaths = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithObjects:dummyKeyIndexPath, nil];
    // define mediaKeyURLs mapping the key dummyKeyIndexPath to the value of the URL string we want
    mediaKeyURLs = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    @"https://playeritemvideourl", dummyKeyIndexPath,
                    nil];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 100;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TextCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    // this is the row of dummyMediaIndexPath defined in -viewDidLoad
    if (indexPath.row == 40)
    {
        self.playerController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
        NSString *videoURLString = @"https://playeritemvideourl";
        AVPlayer *player = [mediaPlayers objectForKey:videoURLString]; // load player with URL
        if (!player)
        {
            player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoURLString]];
            NSLog(@"Video with URL: %@ was not preloaded. Loading now.", videoURLString);
        }
        self.playerController.player = player;
//      [player play];
// present your playerController here
        [cell setText:@"Player cell"];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell #%li", (long)indexPath.row]];
    }
    
    return cell;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // get visible rows
    NSArray *visibleRows = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    // traverse through rows
    for (NSIndexPath *i in visibleRows)
    {
        // we use an NSSet to quickly determine if i is contained in mediaKeyIndexPaths
        if ([mediaKeyIndexPaths containsObject:i])
        {
            [mediaKeyIndexPaths removeObject:i]; // we only need to load a player once
            NSString *videoURLString = [mediaKeyURLs objectForKey:i];
            NSLog(@"Preloading URL: %@", videoURLString); // for information purposes only
            AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoURLString]];
            [mediaPlayers setObject:player forKey:videoURLString];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

This is about as specific as I can make with the amount of code and information you provided. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any complete example on how to do this?

Comment: I updated to include a simple example.

Comment: Thank you i tried the first option where i need to download everything first and then load the avplayer. The problem is that when i scroll the first time seems to be working but if i scroll to the next image and then back again i get black screen...any thoughts or ideas what might be happening?

Comment: @stefanosn Without more information about your implementation, it is hard to pinpoint a solution. Just to shoot you a guess, make sure that you are retaining your AVPlayers and making sure that they aren't getting released after they are scrolled past. Also make sure that when you scroll back, either resume or restart streaming when a cell is visible.

Comment: I'll give you more info. I add the avplayers to a nsmutablearray called globalAvPlayers that is instatiated in appdelegate -> https://pastebin.com/Tv5Uhtcv ...so i am doing this once the app starts. For each table view cell i instatiate a playbackcontroller with an avplayer. This is the implementation of the UItableviewcell https://pastebin.com/jvLsrUzR and the implementation of the playercontroller https://pastebin.com/ME9HpkMi . Here is the code of the playerview which exists in playercontroller https://pastebin.com/5FMHvarD . Tried to use the globalAvPlayers in playercontroller...

Comment: As it is now the code at pastebin.com/ME9HpkMi which is for the playercontroller you will notice that each time a cell appears a new avplayer loads. This is what i understand. So i thought that if i load the globalAvPlayers as you said using the videoURL it will play...As i understand i am not doing something right. I have the original code without my changes at pastebin.com/ME9HpkMi . You will notice that i have done some changes but either i have commented out at line 629 and 692. So i am trying this specific code to make it work as you suggested...please if you have any suggestions tell me.

Comment: @stefanosn Right now you are presenting a lot of code, and even in that code, there are still so many unknowns that have not been presented. Please narrow down your code to the applicable bits if you still have questions. Use breakpoints and step through the code line by line. For example, set a breakpoint every time you load a cell so you can see if the assets are loading properly. I can't run your code so you have to provide me ALL of the details. You say your are getting a black screen... You need to expand on that. Is your ViewController present? Is your AVPlayer nil? Please expand!!!

Comment: @stefanosn In addition to expanding, please eliminate the code that isn't applicable to the problem. It doesn't help in solving your problem. Narrow down to just the applicable bits, and make sure you explain ALL of the applicable bits.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions i will narrow down the issue and let you know. Thanks sir.

Comment: Hello again sir. After many many hours i managed to make the video play fast but i am having the following issue. The first time the video loads everything is fine the video plays  correctly. If i try to reload the same video by scrolling up and then down to the video i was before then the video plays but it freezes at some random point and i hear only sound. I am thinking that this has to do with the AvPlayerLayer that exists in my C8PlayerView UIView class. I tried also to make the AvPlayerLayer nil before setting the cached avplayer. Please check this file... https://pastebin.com/Xjytb8Gt

Comment: Any suggestions please sir i am struggling to find the answer i am out of ideas... this is the viewcontroller code: https://pastebin.com/6CSGr9Ue . Inside the viewcontroller exists the C8PlayerView as a property. The C8PlayerView UIView class i mentioned in the above comment. Please help sir...